# C++: Segmentation fault when inserting pointer into a struct's double pointer array

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have a TreeNode class with the following definition, containing a double pointer that points to an array of TreeNode pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef struct TreeNode { 
   int key;
   int val;
   bool flag;
   int num_children;
   TreeNode **children;
} TreeNode;
```

In the following code:

```
TreeNode* node1 = new TreeNode{1, 1, true, 0, NULL};
TreeNode* node2 = new TreeNode{2, 2, true, 0, NULL};
TreeNode* node3 = new TreeNode{3, 2, true, 0, NULL};
TreeNode* node4 = new TreeNode{4, 2, true, 0, NULL};
TreeNode* node5 = new TreeNode{5, 2, true, 0, NULL};

// Assign node2 to be the child of node1
node1->children = &node2;
cout << "Assigned node1->children = &node2;" << endl;

// Assign node3 to be the second child of node1
node1->children[1] = node3;
cout << "Assigned node1->children[1] = node3;" << endl;
node1->children[2] = node4;
cout << "Assigned node1->children[2] = node4;" << endl;
node1->children[3] = node5;
cout << "Assigned node1->children[3] = node3;" << endl;
```

I get a segmentation fault at the following line of code:

```
node1->children[2] = node4;
```

This seems strange considering that I have dynamically allocated memory using the new keyword. Furthermore, I can't allocate a fixed amount of memory to the array, since the children array can change size at any moment in the program.

Comment: You siad `children of array can change size at any moment`, sounds like you need dynamic array like `vector` rather than static arrays. may be `std::vector<std::vector<TreeNode> > children`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
node1->children = &node2;
```

So, `node1->children` contains the address of `node2`.

```
node1->children[2] = node4;
```

This doesn't make sense. Since `node1->children` contains a pointer to `node2` and not an array, `node1->children[2]` doesn't exist -- no space has been allocated for it, so its value can't be set.

You want an array of pointers, but nowhere do you create any space to store an array of pointers.

Your code is conceptually no different from this:

```
int a;
int *b = &a;
b[1] = 7;
```

While `b[0]` points to `a`, `b[1]` is not valid and so can't be assigned a value. If we want an array of pointers to `int`, somewhere we need to make space for one. There has to be a `new int*[2]` somewhere.

You probably wanted to do something like `node1->children = new TreeNode*[5];`  to allocate an array of 5 pointers to `TreeNode`s. Then you can set `node->children[0]` through `node->children[4]` to point to whatever you want once you have a place to store an array of pointers.